# selectize.js : to clear selected value in onChange event

Tags: onchange, selectize.js

I am trying to clear out the value selected in the onChange event depending on a condition. Whether or not its already present in a selected list. 
However i am not able to clear of the value using
`$select[name][0].selectize.clear();` from inside the onChange object. I tried various versions of it , like using the elements id. 
Please help me with this.

```
$select[name].selectize({
valueField: 'lot_name',
labelField: 'lot_name',
create: true,
options: res,
render: {
    option: function (item, escape) {
         return '<div>' +
             '<span><strong>' + item.lot_name + '</strong></span>' +
             '</div>';
     },
     option_create: function (data, escape) {
      return '<div class="create">Map to <strong>' + escape(data.input) + '</strong>&hellip;</div>';
     }
 },
onChange: function (value) {
     if($.inArray(value, selectedList) > -1){
         alert("Lot " + value + " has already been selected. Please recheck your selection and  try again");
    $select[name][0].selectize.clear();
     } else {
          // else logic
     }
 }
});
```

Comment: do u mind deleeting some of that extra left-space? it looks good just too much to right

Comment: $('#select-with-selectize-triggered-on')[0].selectize.removeOption(value);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the solution I found.

```
     /* Using the Below inside onChange event handler
      var obj = $(this);
      obj[0].setValue("");
     */


onChange: function (value) {
 var obj = $(this);
 if (($.inArray(value, selectedList) > -1)) {
   alert("Lot " + value + " has already been selected. Please recheck your selection and try again");
   obj[0].setValue("");
 } else {
}
},
```