# Displaying dynamic search results dropdown

Tags: selectize.js

I'mn using selectize to load dynamic search results using an ASP.Net webservice, and no problems with that. However, in order to display the dropdown of results I have to lose and regain focus from the selectize control (which deletes the text), or delete what I have typed.

How to display the results dropdown when I type? This is code I am using

```
$('#input-tags3').selectize(
{
valueField : 'id',
labelField : 'name',
searchfield : 'name',
plugins : ['remove_button'],
options : [],
delimiter : ',',
highlight : true,
persist : true,
hideselected : true,
create : false,
load : function (query, callback)
{
    if (!query.length || query.length < 3)
        return callback();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : '../data/WebService1.asmx/GetLookup',
        data : "pSearchType=CAC&pQuery=" + query,
        type : 'GET',
        error : function ()
        {
            callback();
        },
        success : function (res)
        {
            callback(res);
        }
    }
    );
}
score : function (search)
{
    var score = this.getScoreFunction(search);
    return function (item)
    {
        return score(item) * (1 + Math.min(item.watchers / 100, 1));
    };
},
render :
{
    item : function (item, escape)
    {

        return '<div>'
         + '<b>' + item.id + '</b><p>' + item.name + '</p></div>'

    },
    option : function (item, escape)
    {

        return '<div>'
         + '<b>' + item.id + '</b><p>' + item.name + '</p></div>'

    }
}
});
```

Also, the above code appends any dynamic results to the dropdown, and doesn't clear it as expected.

Comment: Note: The score function was copied from the documentation for selectize.js on retrieving remote data from GitHub; it is not only irrelevant to the current question, but also buggy unless the source of the remote data returns that data with a `watchers` attribute that can be used for scoring. I've removed this function from my own code to no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add onChange event to your input, like in this question: [selectize.js : to clear selected value in onChange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954990/selectize-js-to-clear-selected-value-in-onchange-event)